# Unity2D: Spawn objects using array and deleting spawn object once exit out of camera view

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

Is there an easier way of controlling how many enemies I want to spawn in within the inspector, instead of me keep on copying and pasting the same method in my code but renaming it. Um I think using an array (example):

[image: array]

Should do the trick but I don't know how to implement it into my code. Please and thank you! :)

My code:

```
public GameObject enemy;

// Variable to know how fast we should create new enemies
public float spawnTime = 2;


void Start() {  
    // Call the 'addEnemy' function every 'spawnTime' seconds
    InvokeRepeating ("addEnemy", spawnTime, spawnTime);

}
// New function to spawn an enemy
void addEnemy() {  
    // Variables to store the X position of the spawn object
    // See image below
    var x1 = transform.position.x - GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;
    var x2 = transform.position.x + GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x / 2;
    // Randomly pick a point within the spawn object
    var spawnPoint = new Vector2 (Random.Range (x1, x2), transform.position.y);
    // Create an enemy at the 'spawnPoint' position
    Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
 }
}
```

P.s. Does anyone know how to delete the spawned object once it exit out of the main camera's view. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to control how many objects you want to spawn, but I found a turnaround using your code.

1. Declare two variables that tells the max amount of objects to spawn and the current amount of objects in the scene `public int spawnMax = 6, currentTotal = 0;`
2. Add this line to addEnemy function `if (currentTotal >= spawnMax) CancelInvoke("addEnemy");`

For deleting objects outside of the camera view I would put an empty gameobjects as a children of the camera, and in the children put colliders that mach the borders of the camera view, and finally use tags and [OnCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)/[OnTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) functions to detect if any object is outside.

Answer (score 0):

The whole trick is you have to keep an empty gameObject behind the view(Users view) lets call it destroyer .Add a tag to the Game objects so that u can identify the objects that are colliding with destroyer.Check for tags if they qualify to be destroyed then use Destroy (gameObject) should destroy the gameObject.

Comment: Thank you for that but the main issue I want to solve first is to spawn objects using arrays, the picture above is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you for your response. :)